# Addition of Two Elements of Group Representation (Quantum Mechanics angular momentum)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-mechanics

In Sakurai Modern Quantum Mechanics I saw the author takes commutation of two infinitesimal 3D rotation matrices. He also claims that the Hilbert space rotation operators should satisfy the same commutation relation.

1. What does it mean to subtract two elements in the representation of a group, namely, lets say $R(ε)$ to be infinitesimal matrix by infinitesimal angle $ε$ then what does
   $$
   R_x(ε)R_y(ε) - R_y(ε)R_x(ε) = R_z(ε^2)-1
   $$
   mean? How can we subtract rotations from each other because rotations form a group in which multiplication operation is defined (applying rotations consecutively). But we do not have any addition operation in rotation group, so how do we have such an operation in the representation of the group and what does it mean such things like the infinitesimal rotation commutations are related to second order infinitesimal rotations around some other axis.
2. *He also claims that the Hilbert space rotation operators should satisfy the same commutation relation.* How can he be sure about this statement

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @baba To answer your first question: a representation takes group elements to matrices (or if you prefer, to linear operators). The outputs of a representation can be added even though addition is not defined within the context of the original group

Comment: Thank you for your answer but: what does it mean such things like the infinitesimal rotation commutations are related to second order infinitesimal rotations around some other axis. I mean if such a relation exists in the representation, shouldn't there be something similar in the group structure. I just cannot get the intuition.

Comment: @baba Perhaps a helpful thing to keep in mind, then, is that representations also preserve the differential structure of a group. The "addition" that occurs within $R_x(ε)R_y(ε) - R_y(ε)R_x(ε) = R_z(ε^2)-1$, to the extent that it makes sense within the context of the original group, takes place within the tangent space to the group at the identity (i.e. the group's Lie algebra). We can add/subtract infinitessimal rotations (or at least give definitive answers to these expressions) because these correspond to addition/subtraction within the tangent space.

Comment: It is a formal approximation of the matrices involved in the 3d representation of the relevant [group commutator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/721060/66086).